# changing a string to double returning one

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsstring

I have stored a value 1/129600.0 in a plist as a string.
I am able to retrieve it as a string but when i am trying to convert it as a double i am getting it as 1.0.I have also tried CFString

```
NSString *value = [[self array]objectAtIndex:m];
double a = [value doubleValue];
NSLog(@"%@",value);
NSLog(@"%f",a);
```

and in log the returned values are
 1/129600.0 and 1.0

Comment: you can use UIWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString to call it for javascript,it is like "eval(expression)", value=@"1/1296...";value = [NSString stringWithFormat@"eval(%@)",value];and to call stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works fine, I tried it in xCode:

```
NSString *equation = [[self array]objectAtIndex:m];
NSExpression *result = [NSExpression expressionWithFormat:equation];

NSNumber *a = [result expressionValueWithObject:nil context: nil];

NSLog(@"%@",result);
NSLog(@"%.10f",[a doubleValue]);
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess 1/129600.0 is not a valid number.

Try to create an expression and create an NSNumber from it:

```
NSString *equation = [[self array]objectAtIndex:m];
NSNumber *a = [[NSExpression expressionWithFormat:equation] expressionValueWithObject:nil context:nil];
double a = [result doubleValue];
NSLog(@"%f", a);
```

Answer (score 1):

`1/129600.0` is not a valid representation for a number in most programming languages, including ObjC. You need to parse the string and interpret it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
NSString *value = [[self array]objectAtIndex:m];
NSArray *arr = [value componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
double a;
if ([arr count] == 2)
{
   a = [arr objectAtIndex:0]/[arr objectAtIndex:1];
}
NSLog(@"%@",value);
NSLog(@"%f",a);
```